# TypeError: undefined

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to set up an `Add Question` button function but I am off to a bad start. I am receiving a error stating:

TypeError: form.questionText is undefined

What am I doing wrong?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function insertQuestion(form) {

            var questionarea = (form.questionText.length) ? form.questionText[0] : form.questionText;

        }


    </script>

<table id="question">
<tr>
    <td>Question:</td> 
    <td>
        <textarea class="questionTextArea" id="mainTextarea" rows="5" cols="40" name="questionText"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>


    <form id="QandA" action="insertQuestion.php" method="post">
        <table id="questionBtn" align="center">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input id="addQuestionBtn" name="addQuestion" type="button" value="Add Question"
                    onClick="insertQuestion(this.form)" />
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <table id="qandatbl" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="13%" class="question">Question</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <div id="qandatbl_onthefly_container">
            <table id="qandatbl_onthefly" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
            border="0">
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here ? Where is `questionText` is defined ?

Comment: I don't see an element with the id of `questionText` defined within your markup.

Comment: @ChaosPandion Sorry I can't believe I forgot to put that in, I have put it in. I do get the undefined error when code is like above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have not defined `questionText` anywere so it will give `undefined` error

Update 1:
And then you have to add your questionText in the `form` where your submit button is:

```
<textarea class="questionTextArea" id="mainTextarea" rows="5" cols="40" name="questionText"></textarea>
```

Comment: Sorry I can't believe I forgot to put that in, I have put it in now in the question, the code above is giving me the undefined error

Comment: i have edited my answer, and i have just run your code on my machine, if i add above edited line in your code then the code is working

Comment: @user1881090 if you want to use jquery then `Explosion Pills` has suggested a good way

Answer (score 0):

The `questionText` element is not inside of the `<form>`.  Move it inside of the form!  Better yet, since you're using jQuery, there's a cleaner way to do this.  Get rid of the JS you have and *after* the html add:

```
$("#addQuestionBtn").on('click', function (e) {
   var questionarea = $("[name=questionText]").val();

   e.preventDefault();
});
```